# UItableViewCell lost focus when reloadSections function used

Tags: ios, uitableview, focus

I have got a very annoying problem which in can't really figure out (maybe I've just created my tableview the wrong way, I'm don't know ). I've got a UITableview with plenty of (grouped) custom cells which all got UItextField upon them (like at your contacts). When I tap a Phone number automatically it will add another Phonefield (also like the contacts book in edit mode).

To achieve the add of another UItableviewCell I update the data en reload the specific part of the table by using

```
[MyTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

And just after that I call

```
[aTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

To maintain the focus of the keyboard. But after the reload I lose Focus on my textfield so I can't continue typing my number without manually refocus the cursor.

a. its really annoying to manually refocus

b. Certain functions get called (at `textFieldDidEndEditing` ) which i don't want to be called unless I manually switch to another Uitextfield.

Hope someone could help me!

I really appreciate you time to read, thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you. But condition over here is, you should use tag for text field

================================================================================

```
cell =(UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];  

        if (nil ==cell) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];    
            UITextField *txtview = [[UITextField alloc]
                                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(93.0,36.0,190.0,94.0)];            
            txtview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            txtview.tag = 15;

            txtview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5 ,0 ,0 ,0); 
            txtview.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:221.0/255.0 green:249.0/255.0
                                                 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];   
            [cell.contentView addSubview:txtShout];
            [txtview release];
        }
        UITextField *txtview = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:15];
        txtview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strText];
```

==========================================================

```
   [mTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    int rows = [mTableView numberOfRowsInSection:2];
    int row = rows-1; //last
    int lastbutonerow = rows-2;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [mTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:2]];

    UITextField *tf = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:15];
    [tf becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I'ts not working still loses focus and keyboard aswell maybe it's because is need to change UItextField into UiView because UITextfield gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only inserted one row, and you know which row it is, you should not use `reloadData`.  You should use [`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a).

Comment: I'm not inserting a row literally, I'm adding an array item. Rebuilding NSdictionaries and reloading the table content so the new row is exposed.

Comment: Adding an item to the array, and then sending `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to the table view, is the way you insert a row.  It sounds like you've done the first part.  You should try doing the second part.